# Using $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+x^3=yx^2$, $x(0)=x_{0}$ to prove inequalities.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+x^3=yx^2$, $x(0)=x_{0}$

,where $x$ : $\mathbb{R}^+ $-> $\mathbb{R} $ and  $y$ : $\mathbb{R}^+ $-> $\mathbb{R} $ with $\int_{0}^{t} y^2(s) ds < \infty$ for all $t$

if $x(t)$ is continuous function satisfying the above equation in $[0,T]$

I need to prove below inequalities. In order to show these, do I need to solve above differential equation? and if so, how can I apply above conditions to prove following inequalities?

[image]

Comment: Write this for first equation: $\$\$$\Large \max_{t\in[0,T]}|x(t)|^2 \le |x(0)|^2e^{\int_0^T|y|^2\,\mathrm ds}.$\$\$$ 2nd eqn: $\$\$$\Large \int_0^T|x|^4\,\mathrm ds < |x(0)|^2+\max_{s\in[0,T]}|x(s)|^2\int_0^Ty^2\,\mathrm ds.$\$\$$

Comment: [Gronwalls lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Comment: Can you explain how i can use gronwalls lemma to prove..?